# Entity Framework Code First One to One Cascade Deletes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Have and "Address" model used by several other models ("Employee" & "Client").
I would call this a one to one relationship, I could be wrong. The address is required by both of the other models. Remove, deletes only the parent object.

Tried in both EF Core and EF6.  Remove deletes the parent object, but not the "Address" object.

```
public class Address
{
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string CityStateZip { get; set; }
}
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Address EmployeeAddress { get; set; }
}
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Address ClientAddress { get; set; }
}
```

No error messages - context.remove simply won't delete the child object.  Complete noob here when it comes to EF.  Sorry, this is probably a very basic question, but please believe that I have searched extensively.  Most solutions suggest a foreign key back to the parent - but, in this case, the child object can be used (but not shared) in several different models.

Comment: You should show the code that doesn't behave as intended. Only seeing the classes isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

The same Address object can be used in multiple Employee and/or Client instances as currently implemented.

The suggestion you received

> Most solutions suggest a foreign key back to the parent - but, in this case, the child object can be used (but not shared) in several different models.

informs Entity Framework that a given Address can only appear in one specific Employee/Client.

You should be able to resolve this by having Employee and Client inherit from a common base class, e.g.

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Address PersonAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    // Other properties that make Employee unique go here
}

public class Client : Person
{
    // Other properties that make Client unique go here
}
```

Then add the backreference to the base class

```
public class Address
{
    public virtual int AddressID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Street { get; set; }
    public virtual string CityStateZip { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Person AddressOf { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, complete noob here.  Is there any way you could modify my original class with your solution? Assume I add the properties back into the Address class?  Getting error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Address' and 'Person'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.'  Or I'll post my modified classes if that would be easier?

Comment: I modified the example to make it complete. Note that Id and Name can also be moved into the common base class. If those are the *only* properties in these two classes, you may wish to think about whether you really need two classes.

Comment: Tried it as you have suggested - got the following error: : 'One or more validation errors were detected during model generation: EntityType 'Person' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType. People: EntityType: EntitySet 'People' is based on type 'Person' that has no keys defined.     I tried moving the "id's" into Person and got an error similar to what I reported first.  And yes, there are many more properties in "Employees" and "Clients" - this is simply an example.  I'm trying to "building block" approach and reuse child entities - maybe I'm going about it the wrong way?

Comment: Move Id into the base class. I'll update the example code to reflect that.